# Allow group shared from nis to use sudo

Tags: sudoers, nis

I trying to enable a group call `acctadm` shared from NIS to use sudo.

Result of `ypcat gropu` looked like:`acctadm:*:1005:god1,god2`

After trying add `%acctadm ALL=(ALL) ALL`, `+acctadm ALL=(ALL) ALL` by visudo and rebooted. 
When I used account god1 and try `sudo echo 123`, I still got error:`god is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason is I didn't really include NIS group in my /etc/group.
You can check if you include NIS group by `getent group`.
If you didn't, add `+:*::` to include all group of NIS group.